# Return a certain count in multi dimensional list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I have a multidimensional list that I would like to return a certain length but idk what code to wrote. For example I have a list below  that I would like to return all numbers that have a length of 4 or more in the list.

```
A=[[2,4,6,8],[2,12,20],[34,35,37,38],[4,8,9,20,21],[5,7,9,12]]
```

I would like my result to be

```
B=[[2,4,6,8],[34,35,37,38],[5,7,9,12]]
```

Comment: Why is `[4,8,9,20,21]` not in the output? it has a length of 5 which is more than 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, based on your desired output, that you actually want the sublists which have a length of 4, not 4 or more, you can use a list comprehension, filtering on whether the length of the sublist is 4 elements:

```
B = [l for l in A if len(l) == 4]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4, 6, 8], [34, 35, 37, 38], [5, 7, 9, 12]]
```

If you do want 4 or more, change `==` to `>=`:

```
B = [l for l in A if len(l) >= 4]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4, 6, 8], [34, 35, 37, 38], [4, 8, 9, 20, 21], [5, 7, 9, 12]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there the first 2 or more numbers. If you need an example I can tell u

Comment: Can you give me an example so I can be sure what you mean?

Comment: Say if I want to get the first 2 or more numbers from each row. I would like my result to be like this A=[[2,4],[2,12],[34,35],[4,8,],[5,7]]

Comment: @Gamer19 you can use `B=[l[:2] for l in A]`